# Tolower Function does not work in c. I write TURAL muzafarov but it returns TURAL MUZAFAROV

Tags: c, ctype

```
    char str[100];
    puts("Enter the string: ");
    // fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    gets(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        if (isupper(str[i]) > 0) {
            str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
        }
        if (islower(str[i]) > 0) {
            str[i] = toupper(str[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("%s", str);
```

MY TOLOWER FUNCTION DOES NOT WORK FOR EXAMPLE
MY INPUT IS: `TURAL muzafarov`
but it returns
`TURAL MUZAFAROV`

Comment: `else if (islower(...`

Comment: You convert to lower case then immediately to upper case in next `if`.

Comment: Do not use `isupper(str[i])>0`. The classification functions are not specified to return positive values if the test is true, just non-zero values. Also, they should be passed an `unsigned char` value. Use `isupper((unsigned char) str[i])`.

Comment: Tural Muzefferli, code with `gets()` attracts down votes.  See [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2410359)

Answer (score 1):

**OP's code errantly converts to lower and then back to upper**

```
    if (isupper(str[i]) > 0) {
        str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
    }
    // All alpha are lower case at this point
    if (islower(str[i]) > 0) {
        str[i] = toupper(str[i]);
    }
```

---

Other issues

**Wrong test**

`is...()` returns zero or non-zero.  Testing the sign bit is amiss. [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74754771/tolower-function-does-not-work-in-c-i-write-tural-muzafarov-but-it-returns-tura/74755751#comment131933943_74754771)

```
    // if (isupper(str[i]) > 0) {
    if (isupper(str[i])) {
```

**Undefined behavior when `str[i] < 0`**

Avoid that by accessing the string as `unsigned char`

**Do not use `gets()`**

It is no longer part of C.  [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2410359)

**Avoid repeatedly calculating the string length**

Simple test for the *null character*

```
// for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
```

---

Amended code with some other fixes too.

```
char str[100];
puts("Enter the string: ");
if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) {  // Test fgets result.
  unsigned char *ustr = (unsigned char *) str;
  for (size_t i = 0; ustr[i]; i++) {  // Use size_t to handle even _long_ strings.
    if (isupper(ustr[i])) {
      ustr[i] = tolower(ustr[i]);
    } else if (islower(ustr[i])) {  // Notice the `else`
      ustr[i] = toupper(ustr[i]);
    }
  }
}
printf("%s", str);
```

Answer (score -1):

You are doing back 2 back two. operation. first you convert string to lowercase then you do uppercase conversion. please remove below code which converts string into uppercase.

```
if(islower(str[i]))
{
     str[i]=toupper(str[i]);
}
```

EDIT:
[C Reference says about toupper()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper)

> int toupper( int ch );
>
> ch    -   character to be converted. If the value of ch is not
> representable as unsigned char and does not equal EOF, the behavior is
> undefined.

hence, below lines are not correct.  the argument to toupper needs to be converted to unsigned char to avoid the risk of undefined behavior.

```
if (isupper(str[i]) > 0) {
    str[i] = tolower( str[i]);
```

change to

```
if(islower((unsigned char)str[i]))
{
     str[i]=toupper((unsigned char)str[i]);
}
```

also need to change below block of code

```
if (islower(str[i]) > 0) {
            str[i] = toupper(str[i]);
```

changed to

```
if (islower((unsigned char)str[i])) {
            str[i] = toupper((unsigned char)str[i]);
```

output:

```
Enter the string: 
TURAL muzafarov
tural muzafarov
```

Comment: `if(islower(str[i])>0) { str[i]=toupper(str[i]); }` is 3 mistakes: You should write `if (islower((unsigned char)str[i])) { str[i] = toupper((unsigned char)str[i]); }`

Comment: also remove the `>0`. the `isxxx()` functions are specified as returning a non zero value. The return value is not necessarily positive.